# How to get customer address in transaction.phtml in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to fetch customer address into the transaction.phtml but i am not getting how to do this . I am trying below but not getting success

Below is the file path where my transaction.phtml file wiil be there & the code i am trying

```
/var/www/html/Myproject/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Lof_CustomerMembership/templates/customer/membership/transactions.phtml


<?php
$helper = $this->helper("Lof\CustomerMembership\Helper\Data");
$transactions = $block->getTransactions();
$address=$block->getPrimaryBillingAddress();

// var_dump($helper);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerId =$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

// $address = $this->myHelper->getCustomerAddressById(Id);
// $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
// $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
// $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBilling(); 
?>
```

Anyone have idea how to get default billing and shipping address then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

try with `$customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()` or `$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()`